# How to retrieve data from 2 database using doctrine in same entity-manager?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem in retrieve data from two difference MySQL databases

```
    $em = $this->doctrine->emDetails;
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('g.gradeId as grade_id', 'g.gradeName as grade_name', 'g.rank', 'ay.academicId as academic_year_id');
    $qb->from('Entity\Grades', 'g');
    $qb->leftjoin('g.academicYear', 'ay');
    $qb->where('ay.academicId = :academicId');
    $qb->setParameter('academicId', $data);
    $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    return $result;
```

`academicYear`  exist in `X` database
and `Grades` exist in `Y` database

i have get the following Error

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'Y.Academic_years' doesn't exist
```

How i can solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To query two different database you need to work with two entity managers.

If you're working with symfony you can find how to do it here :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Official doc explains it very clearly.

Comment: Hi, I'm working with CodeIgniter, and doctrine2,
I have created 2 entity manager, but i can't get data from it

Comment: You should edit your first post with code using 2 entity managers so someone may help you with it.